# ComboBox selection arrow is displaced

Tags: gxt

The arrow of each combobox is displaced in all browsers (i tried firefox, chrome, opera). Does anybody know what the problem could be? Any help is appreciated.

See http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?168487-ComboBox-selection-arrow-is-displaced&p=703835 for further details to this issue (as im currently not allowed to upload a screenshot here.)

See also the below code that causes the issue.

```
public class MyApp implements EntryPoint {
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    LayoutContainer container = new LayoutContainer();

    final SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
    combo.setEmptyText("Select an item...");
    combo.setDisplayField("item");
    combo.setWidth(150);
    combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
    combo.add("Value1");
    combo.add("Value2");
    container.add(combo);
    container.setBorders(true);
    container.layout();
    RootPanel.get().add(container);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out why this is happening. I'm using the Maven GWT plugin in my project, thus I used this plugin to generate the archetype. I have a MyApp.css file that was automatically generated in order to introduce custom css layouts. However, I never looked into that css file. This generated css file contained, amonst others, a top margin for all images. And of course this margin was causing this issue. I think this thread can be closed then.

```
img {
   margin-top: 20px
}
```